# How to create database rows in a transaction with file saving to disk using C# and Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a C# application where I need to create database records within a transaction and simultaneously save files to disk. I'm using Entity Framework Core for the database operations, and standard C# file handling for file operations.

However, I'm struggling to ensure that both database operations and file saving happen atomically within a transaction.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? For example, Sql Server has a [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server) that provides transactional consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to run
`DbContext.SaveChanges()` or `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` within a specific DB strategy instance:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IExecutionStrategy.Execute/ExecuteAsync(....., operation: {...... see below.....}, ....)
```

The strategy is obtained by calling

```
var myStrategy = DbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
```

The DbContext.Dabase must be set to run without auto transaction enabled:
`DbContext.Database.AutoTransactionsEnabled/AutoTransactionBehavior = false;`

Then, inside the `myOwnTransactionAction` passed into the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IExecutionStrategy.Execute\ExecuteAsync`
as the `operation` parameter you need to create your own database transaction

```
var transaction = DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction/BeginTransactionAsync()
```

then you can run your FILESYSTEM stuff. If there is an exception, you can catch and and rollback the transaction:

```
public static bool RunTryCatchRollbackStrategyWithOwnTransaction(IExecutionStrategy myStrategy)
{
    IDbContextTransaction? transaction = null;
    bool result;
    try
    {
       result = myStrategy.Execute
                (
                    state: false,
                    operation:
                        (DbContext ctx, _) =>
                        {
                             transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction();
                             result = RunMySuperDuperFileSystemStaff();
                             if (result) ctx.SaveChanges();
                         },
                     verifySucceeded: 
                         (_, s) => new ExecutionResult<bool>(s, true));
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction?.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
       
    if (result) transaction.Commit(); else transaction.Rollback()
    return result;
}
```

Or just use or be inspired by the following template for "UnitOfWork" - which is acutally another wrapper of the underlaying EF DbContext. It is used in a production. It is well tested for exceptions/rollabacking - not for multi-threading, which should be actually avoided, since it is based on an EF Context.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Jesivorka.Library.Infrastructure.Data.EntityFramework.Context;

/// <summary>
/// The "Unit of Work" template wrapping <see cref="DbContext"/> and implementing
/// the basic <see cref="IUnitOfWork.Commit"/> method using
/// <see cref="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()"/> and
/// <see cref="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)"/>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TDbContext">Specific <see cref="DbContext"/> instance.</typeparam>
/// <remarks>
///  This implementation of <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/> wraps the <see cref="DbContext"/> to
///     1) decouple the repos from the console, controllers, ASP.NET pages....
///     2) decouple the DbContext and EF from the controllers
/// It exposes the <see cref="DbContext"/> for any other entity framework low level data manipulation.
/// </remarks>
/// <seealso href="http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns"/>
/// <seealso cref="IUnitOfWork"/>
public class UnitOfWorkTemplate<TDbContext>
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Service provider, used for resolving services or creating scopes if specific implementation needs it.  
    /// </summary>
    protected IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    protected readonly ILogger Logger;

    private Action? _afterSaveChangesAction;
    private Action? _beforeSaveChangesAction;
    private List<CancellableAction>? _commitActions;
    private readonly object _commitActionSync = new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates instance with specific optional <see cref="DbContext"/>
    /// </summary>
    public UnitOfWorkTemplate(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ServiceProvider = serviceProvider;
        Logger = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(GetType());
        DbContext = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDbContext>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates if the wrapped <see cref="DbContext"/> should be disposed at disposing this instance.
    /// </summary>
    protected TDbContext DbContext { get; private set; }

    public virtual Task<bool> CommitAsync() =>
        RunWithoutAutoTransaction(async (strategy) =>
        {
            IDbContextTransaction? transaction = null;
            bool result;
            try
            {
                result = await strategy.ExecuteAsync(
                    false,
                    async (ctx, _, token) =>
                    {
                        transaction = await ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(token);
                        return await RunRepetitiveSaveActionsAsync(token) && !token.IsCancellationRequested;
                    },
                    (_, s, _) => Task.FromResult(new ExecutionResult<bool>(s, true))
                );
            }
            catch
            {
                if (transaction != null) await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                throw;
            }

            transaction.CommitOrRollback(result);
            return result;
        });

    public virtual bool Commit() =>
        RunWithoutAutoTransaction(strategy =>
        {
            IDbContextTransaction? transaction = null;
            bool result;
            try
            {
                result = strategy.Execute(
                    false,
                    (ctx, _) =>
                    {
                        transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction();
                        return RunRepetitiveSaveActions();
                    },
                    (_, s) => new ExecutionResult<bool>(s, true)
                );
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction?.Rollback();
                throw;
            }

            transaction.CommitOrRollback(result);
            return result;
        });

    public virtual void AddTransactionAction(CancellableAction action)
    {
        lock (_commitActionSync)
        {
            _commitActions ??= new();
            _commitActions.Add(action);
        }
    }

    public virtual void AddAfterCommitAction(Action action) => _afterSaveChangesAction += action;
    public virtual void AddBeforeCommitAction(Action action) => _beforeSaveChangesAction += action;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the <see cref="AddTransactionAction"/> method was called (at least once)
    /// </summary>
    protected bool IsNextTransactionAction
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_commitActionSync) return _commitActions?.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    protected bool RunRepetitiveSaveActions()
    {
        SaveChanges();

        while (IsNextTransactionAction)
        {
            CancellableAction action;
            lock (_commitActionSync) action = _commitActions![0];
            var shouldContinue = action().Result;
            lock (_commitActionSync) _commitActions.RemoveAt(0);
            if (!shouldContinue) return false;

            SaveChanges();
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected async Task<bool> RunRepetitiveSaveActionsAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await SaveChangesAsync(token);

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested && IsNextTransactionAction)
        {
            CancellableAction action;
            lock (_commitActionSync) action = _commitActions![0];
            var shouldContinue = await action();
            lock (_commitActionSync) _commitActions.RemoveAt(0);
            if (!shouldContinue || token.IsCancellationRequested) return false;

            await SaveChangesAsync(token);
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void SaveChanges()
    {
        var beforeAction = _beforeSaveChangesAction;
        var afterAction = _afterSaveChangesAction;
        try
        {
            _beforeSaveChangesAction = null;
            _afterSaveChangesAction = null;

            beforeAction?.Invoke();
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
            afterAction?.Invoke();
        }
        catch
        {
            _afterSaveChangesAction = afterAction;
            _beforeSaveChangesAction = beforeAction;
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected async Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var beforeAction = _beforeSaveChangesAction;
        var afterAction = _afterSaveChangesAction;
        try
        {
            _beforeSaveChangesAction = null;
            _afterSaveChangesAction = null;

            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested) beforeAction?.Invoke();
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested) await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(token);
            if (!token.IsCancellationRequested) afterAction?.Invoke();
        }
        catch
        {
            _afterSaveChangesAction = afterAction;
            _beforeSaveChangesAction = beforeAction;
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected TResult RunWithoutAutoTransaction<TResult>(Func<IExecutionStrategy, TResult> ownTransactionAction)
    {
        var database = DbContext.Database;
        var autoTransactionsEnabled = database.AutoTransactionsEnabled;
        try
        {
            var strategy = database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            return ownTransactionAction(strategy);
        }
        finally
        {
            database.AutoTransactionsEnabled = autoTransactionsEnabled;
        }
    }

    protected Task<TResult> RunWithoutAutoTransaction<TResult>(Func<IExecutionStrategy, Task<TResult>> ownTransactionAction)
        => RunWithoutAutoTransaction<Task<TResult>>(ownTransactionAction);
}

public static class IDbContextTransactionExtensions
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void CommitOrRollback(this IDbContextTransaction? transaction, bool commit)
    {
        if (transaction == null) return;

        if (commit)
        {
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can added nested actions with already added actions dynamically using some boolean condition, e.g.

```
var unitOfWork = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UnitOfWorkTemplate>();

//first step in the transaction
unitOfWork.AddBeforeCommitAction(() => { Console.WriteLine("1-st message"); });
// at the background: dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
unitOfWork.AddAfterCommitAction(() => { Console.WriteLine("2-nd message");  });

unitOfWork.AddTransactionAction(MySuperDuperFileSystemStuffAsync); //second step in the transaction

// third step in the transaction adding before/after commit actions dynamically
unitOfWork.AddTransactionAction
(
    async () => {
        Console.WriteLine("7-th message after calling finishing MySuperDuperFileSystemStuff");

        unitOfWork.AddBeforeCommitAction(() => { Console.WriteLine("8-th message");  });
        // at the background: dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
        unitOfWork.AddAfterCommitAction(() => { Console.WriteLine("9-th message"); });
    
       return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
);

// executing transaction and all added transaction or commit actions
await unitOfWork.CommitAsync();



// this is the second step in the transaction - it does add dynamically last action if there is need to add it
public static async Task<bool> MySuperDuperFileSystemStuffAsync()
{
    Console.Write("3-rd message: This is called as second step within a transaction after calling first SaveChanges");
    
    bool someRelevantCondition = true;

    if (someRelevantCondition)
    {
       unitOfWork.AddTransactionAction(async () => {
           Console.Write("10-th message");

           return Task.FromResult(true);
       })

       unitOfWork.AddBeforeCommitAction(() => { console.WriteLine("4-th message");  });
       // at the background: dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
       unitOfWork.AddAfterCommitAction(() => { console.WriteLine("5-th message");  });
    }

    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```